# I have a list of colors, I need to parse them as backgrounds to html elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, parsing

I have a list of 600 colors in RGB format that I am trying to parse to html elements as background colors when the page loads. Colors are currently in CSV form but that can be changed of course. HTML elements can be created by the script itself or be existing, either way is workable from my end.

Here is an example that I now have functioning

```
var color = [];
color[ 0 ] = 'RGB(233,232,217)';
color[ 1 ] = 'RGB(227,222,202)';
color[ 2 ] = 'RGB(218,210,186)';
color[ 3 ] = 'RGB(208,189,150)';
color[ 4 ] = 'RGB(213,208,194)';

$.each(color, function(index, value){
    $('body').append($('<a class="color">').css({
        height: '30px',
        width: '30px',
        'background-color': value
    })
);
});
```

Comment: bro you gotta be more specific. do you want to do this with a onclick? as the page loads? really define your question

Comment: In what format is your color list. Is it JSON? XML? or...

Comment: please clarify the issue you are facing... with some sample code

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight Sorry I should have mentioned that. This will just be on page load, the html elements can either be created ahead of time and just populated with an inline style, or create by the script itself. I can put the colors into any format needed, currently they're in a CSV file.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this CSV as well as jQuery/JavaScript of attempts.

Comment: please edit your question instead of explaining in a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is render the colors in separate elements, you can do something like the following (assuming your "list" is a simple array):

```
$.each(colors, function(index, value){
    $('body').append($('<div>').css({
            'background-color': value,
            height: '30px',
            width: '100px' // Set height and width to whatever size is best for you
        })
     );
});
```

Comment: This is **exactly** what I was looking for concerning direction. Already have a small version of it working, thank you so much.